# Как на андроид организовать динамическую загрузку ресурсов?

Tags: android, java

Пишу небольшое приложение и встала задача по организации меню в котором каждая кнопка содержит картинку в виде логотипа или фото(неважно), текст-название и информацию по ней. Я разобрался с текстовой частью. Организовал небольшое АПИ посредством JSON и подгружаю его в приложение, а теперь стоит вопрос как быть с картинками? Т.е. как их загрузить на устройство, куда так чтобы я мог их использовать при построении меню из лист вью, как я понимаю стандартные ресурсы я заменять не могу. Буду рад любой помощи! Простите за такой сумбурный вопрос!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на библиотеку [Universal Image Loader](http://nostra13android.blogspot.ru/2012/03/4-universal-image-loader-part-1.html). Возможно это то, что вам нужно.